# How to create an update trigger where an insert operation is performed?

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, updates

Consider below is my table,

```
register_device

id | user_id | device_id | status | 

1  |  12     |  1234      |   1    | 
2  |  1      |  5678      |   1    | 
3  |  11     |  1456      |   1    |
```

Logic for trigger:

Before inserting value in register_device table, i want to check whether the new device_id value already exist in register_device table. If in case the value is already present its status need to be changed to 0, before inserting a new value, like below.

```
id | user_id | device_id | status | 

1  |  12     |  1234      |   0    | 
2  |  1      |  5678      |   1    | 
3  |  11     |  1456      |   1    |
4  |  14     |  1234      |   1    |
```

So when i run insert operation through coding, trigger need to perform the above logic by its own in database.

Comment: This is going to be hard to do.  You can't use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` because you actually want to insert a record anyway, and you also can't use a trigger.

Comment: could you please suggest any alternative approach for this logic.

Comment: If the _same_ user were to try to insert the _same_ `device_id`, should that fail or should it be allowed?

Comment: it should be allowed but it need to be inserted in new row after updating the status of previous row to 0

Comment: _Which_ previous row?  There could be more than one.  Hopefully you see the complexity of this.

Comment: No problem if its more then one. The only criteria is if the (already_exist_device_id) = (new_device_id) and status = 1, then those columns status need to changed to 0.

Comment: I have an alternative solution in mind which gets around these problems.  Should I post it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148599/discussion-between-mani-kandan-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is going to make it very difficult to implement your insert logic for several reasons:

- You can't use a trigger because a trigger cannot modify the table which caused it to fire
- Using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` also won't fly because you actually want to insert the record even if an update also happens

I propose a slightly different table design:

```
id | user_id | device_id | status_timestamp
```

The only change here is that `status` has become `status_timestamp`, which is a `timestamp` column.  You can insert records and use `NOW()` for the current timestamp value.

Logically speaking, any record which does *not* have the max value of `status_timestamp` for a given `device_id` would correspond to a zero `status` in your original table.  And records having the max `status_timestamp` value for a given `device_id` would correspond to a `status` of 1.

For example, to get the status=1 record for `device_id` 1234 you could use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM register_device
WHERE device_id = 1234
ORDER BY status_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

And to get all the status=0 records for `device_id` 1234 you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM register_device
WHERE device_id = 1234 AND
      status_timestamp < (SELECT MAX(status_timestamp) FROM register_device
                          WHERE device_id = 1234)
```